# Take n element except from dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, except, take

I have this code:

```
var items = from pair in dic orderby pair.Value descending select pair;
var top5 = items.Take(5);
```

I take five items from a Dictionary string,int in descending order

```
var keys = String.Join(", ", top5.Select(x => String.Format("{0}", x.Key)).ToArray().Except(res.Keys));
```

Here I show the 5 items but I except some words placed in another Dictionary string, string. If I except one word in the top5 I will display less than 5 elements.

How can I display always 5 elements although I except some words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var items = from pair in dic orderby pair.Value descending select pair;
var keys = items.Select(x => String.Format("{0}", x.Key)).ToArray().Except(res.Keys);
var top5 = keys.Take(5);
var result = String.Join(", ", top5);
```

Do the `.Take` after you've done the exclusion. And then do the formatting. You can combine some of these into one linq statement.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was thinking and changing codebut finally has been a simple change! :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `Except` is to add a `where` clause in the LINQ expression:

```
var items = (from pair in dic
             orderby pair.Value descending
             where !res.ContainsKey(pair.Key.ToString())
             select pair);
var top5 = items.Take(5).ToArray();
```